# Mapping data between 2 tables Using Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Data of Table 1

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER   ! ISSUANCE_NUMBER
1007143737797943 !   448866
1007143738206753  !  163026
1007143739416658  !  202092
1007143740424543  !  772829
1007143741130461  !  124043
```

Data in Table 2

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  ISSUANCENO  SEQUENCE_NUMBER
               !              1007143737
               !              1007143738
                !             1007143739
               !              1007143740
               !              1007143741
```

SEQUENCE_NUMBER in table 2 is first 10 digit of Account number. how can I map Account number and Issuanceno using Pandas and Python in second Table?

OUTPUT :

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  !ISSUANCENO !SEQUENCE_NUMBER
007143737797943   ! 448866  !  1007143737
1007143738206753  !  163026 !  1007143738
1007143739416658   ! 202092 !  1007143739
1007143740424543   ! 772829 !  1007143740
1007143741130461   ! 124043 !  1007143741
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Converting 16 digit into 10 digit
excel_file = 'TTT_cardno.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
df = df['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'].floordiv(100_000)
#print(df) # printing 10 digit number
# Reading 2nd file
excel_file1 = 'card_no.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file1)
df1 = df1['CARD_SEQUENCE_NUMBER']
#print(df1)
# creating a 3rd dataframe using both the dataframe
df3 = df1.assign(ACCOUNT_NUMBER=df.iloc[:,0], ISSUANCENO= df.iloc[:,1])
print(df3)
```

ERROR:- AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first 10 digits of the Account Number (in the first table) like this.  (`floordiv` is integer division)

```
df['SEQUENCE_NUMBER'] = df['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'].floordiv(100_000)
print(df)

     ACCOUNT_NUMBER  ISSUANCE_NUMBER  SEQUENCE_NUMBER
0  1007143737797943           448866      10071437377
1  1007143738206753           163026      10071437382
2  1007143739416658           202092      10071437394
3  1007143740424543           772829      10071437404
4  1007143741130461           124043      10071437411
```

Then, use `.merge()` on the Sequence Number, to connect the two tables.

Comment: pandas can read from database tables; docs are here: [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign)

```
df2 = df2.assign(ACCOUNT_NUMBER=df1.iloc[:,0], ISSUANCENO= df1.iloc[:,1])
df2
     ACCOUNT_NUMBER  ISSUANCENO  SEQUENCE_NUMBER
0  1007143737797943      448866       1007143737
1  1007143738206753      163026       1007143738
2  1007143739416658      202092       1007143739
3  1007143740424543      772829       1007143740
4  1007143741130461      124043       1007143741
```